# How do I store all my class values labeled "price" into an array so I can sort them?

Tags: javascript

How I can store all my price values into an empty array so I can sort them with my "sort: low to high button"? Most examples of sort() I see online have an array with integers already in them and then are sorted, But my issue is I would like to store all my `<h4>` class price values into an array and then sort. Am I going about this the wrong way?

```js
function filterItems(e) {
    const items = document.querySelectorAll(".item"); //selects all menu items
    let filter = e.target.dataset.filter; //grabs value in the event target's data-filter attribute
    // if filter all button is clicked, loop through all items and remove the hidden class
    if (filter === "*") {
        items.forEach(item => item.classList.remove("hidden"));
    } else {
    //loops through all items
    items.forEach(item => {
        item.classList.contains(filter) //does item have the same data-filter in its class list
        ? item.classList.remove('hidden') //if true ?, make sure css class .hidden is NOT applied
        : item.classList.add('hidden'); // if false : does not have same filter tag, apply .hidden css class
    });
};
};
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
    background:#e5e5e5;
    color:#14213d;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin:0;
}

/* everything in the middle */

.container {
    margin:auto;
    max-width:1170px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:center;
    text-align:center;
    align-items:center;
}

h1{
    margin-bottom:12px;
}

hr.solid {
    width:150px;
    border-top: 3px solid #fca311;
  }


/* button styles */
button {
    padding: 6px 15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    border: 2px solid #14213d;
    color:#14213d;
    background-color:#e5e5e5;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#14213d;
}

#flex-buttons {
    margin-top:10px;
}

/*CSS GRID Menu Section */

.food-items-container {
    width: 90vw;
    /*  it aligns the items inside their grid areas on the inline axis */
    justify-items: center;
    display:grid;
    gap: 1rem 2rem;
    grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
    margin-top:50px;
}

.food-items-container img {
   width:220px;
   height:200px;
   object-fit:cover;
   border: 2.8px solid #fca311;
}

hr.border {
    width:100%;
    border:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fca311;
  }

/* Item Content */
.item {
    display: grid;
    gap: 1rem 2rem;
    max-width: 25rem;
}

.item-info header {
    display: flex;
    /* Indents Price */
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .item-info h4 {
    margin-top:5px;
  }

  .item-text {
    text-align:left;
  }

  .price {
    color:#fca311;
  }

  .hidden {
    display:none;
  }

  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    min-width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: #14213d;
    padding: 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }

  .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}

.checked {
    color: orange;
  }

.stars {
  text-align:left;
  margin-top:-10px;
}
  

  @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .item {
      grid-template-columns: 225px 1fr;
      gap: 0 1.25rem;
      max-width: 40rem;
    }
    .food-items-container img {
      height: 175px;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .food-items-container {
      width: 95vw;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    }
    .food-items-container img {
      height: 150px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Restaurant-Menu-App</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href= "style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class ="container">
        <h1>Our Menu</h1>
        <hr class="border">
         <!--Filter Buttons -->

         <!--adding event listener to each of filters to call function, passing filter value -->
            <div id ="flex-buttons">
            <button type ="button" class="filter" data-filter="*" onclick=filterItems(event)>All</button>
            <button type ="button" class="filter" data-filter="breakfast" onclick=filterItems(event)>Breakfast</button>
            <button type ="button" class="filter" data-filter="lunch" onclick=filterItems(event)>Lunch</button>
            <button type ="button" class="filter" data-filter="drink" onclick=filterItems(event)>Drinks</button>
            <button type ="button" class="filter" data-filter="dinner" onclick=filterItems(event)>Dinner</button>
                <div class="dropdown">
                <button type ="button" class="dropbtn">Sort</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <button type ="button" role ="btn" id="sort-price-low" onclick=>Sort: Price Low to High</button>
                    <button type ="button" role ="btn" id="sort-price-high">Sort: Price High to Low</button>
                    <a href="#">Sort: Rating</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                <!-- Menu Section -->
            <div class="food-items-container">
                <div class="item breakfast">
                    <img src="/img/avocado.jpg">
                    <div class="item-info">
                        <header>
                        <h4>Avocado Toast</h4>
                        <h4 class="price">$16.99</h4>
                        </header>
                        <div class="stars">
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="border">
                        <p class="item-text">
                            Nesciunt ipsum dolor sit amet excepturi adipisicing elit.
                            Repudiandae, sint quam. Et reprehenderit fugiat nesciunt inventore
                            laboriosam excepturi!
                          </p>
                          
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item lunch">
                    <img src="/img/burger.jpg">
                    <div class="item-info">
                        <header>
                        <h4>Big Burger</h4>
                        <h4 class="price">$25.99</h4>
                        </header>
                        <div class="stars">
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="border">
                        <p class="item-text">
                            Lorem consectetur dolor sit laboriosam elit.
                            Repudiandae, sint quam. Et reprehenderit fugiat nesciunt.
                          </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item drink">
                    <img src="/img/gentleman.jpg">
                    <div class="item-info">
                        <header>
                        <h4>The Gentleman</h4>
                        <h4 class="price">$10.99</h4>
                        </header>
                        <div class="stars">
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="border">
                        <p class="item-text">
                            Lorem reprehenderit dolor sit elit reprehenderit. Repudiandae, sint quam. Et reprehenderit fugiat.
                          </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item drink">
                    <img src="/img/marg.jpg">
                    <div class="item-info">
                        <header>
                        <h4>Silly Margarita</h4>
                        <h4 class="price">$12.99</h4>
                        </header>
                        <div class="stars">
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="border">
                        <p class="item-text">
                            Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis.
                          </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item drink">
                    <img src="/img/mojito.jpg">
                    <div class="item-info">
                        <header>
                        <h4>Clean Mojito</h4>
                        <h4 class="price">$13.99</h4>
                        </header>
                        <div class="stars">
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span> 
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="border">
                        <p class="item-text">
                            At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium
                            voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi.
                          </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item drink">
                    <img src="/img/old.jpg">
                    <div class="item-info">
                        <header>
                        <h4>Old Fashioned</h4>
                        <h4 class="price">$13.99</h4>
                        </header>
                        <div class="stars">
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span> 
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="border">
                        <p class="item-text">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                            Repudiandae, sint quam. Et reprehenderit fugiat nesciunt inventore
                            laboriosam excepturi! Quo, officia.
                          </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item breakfast">
                    <img src="/img/om.jpg">
                    <div class="item-info">
                        <header>
                        <h4>Cheddar Omelette</h4>
                        <h4 class="price">$17.99</h4>
                        </header>
                        <div class="stars">
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span> 
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="border">
                        <p class="item-text">
                            Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit
                            voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.
                          </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item breakfast">
                    <img src="/img/pancakes.jpg">
                    <div class="item-info">
                        <header>
                        <h4>The Stacked Pancake</h4>
                        <h4 class="price">$17.99</h4>
                        </header>
                        <div class="stars">
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span> 
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="border">
                        <p class="item-text">
                            Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.
                          </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item dinner">
                    <img src="/img/pasta.jpg">
                    <div class="item-info">
                        <header>
                        <h4>Meat Pasta</h4>
                        <h4 class="price">$28.99</h4>
                        </header>
                        <div class="stars">
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span> 
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="border">
                        <p class="item-text">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                            Repudiandae, sint quam. Et reprehenderit fugiat nesciunt inventore
                            laboriosam excepturi! Quo, officia.
                          </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item dinner">
                    <img src="/img/pizza.jpg">
                    <div class="item-info">
                        <header>
                        <h4>Spinach Pizza</h4>
                        <h4 class="price">$20.99</h4>
                        </header>
                        <div class="stars">
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span> 
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="border">
                        <p class="item-text">
                            Vivamus elementum semper nisi.
                          </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item lunch">
                    <img src="/img/salad.jpg">
                    <div class="item-info">
                        <header>
                        <h4>Salad</h4>
                        <h4 class="price">$12.99</h4>
                        </header>
                        <div class="stars">
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span> 
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="border">
                        <p class="item-text">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                            Repudiandae, sint quam. Et reprehenderit fugiat nesciunt inventore
                            laboriosam excepturi! Quo, officia.
                          </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item dinner">
                    <img src="/img/salmon.jpg">
                    <div class="item-info">
                        <header>
                        <h4>Atlantic Salmon</h4>
                        <h4 class="price">$30.99</h4>
                        </header>
                        <div class="stars">
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span> 
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="border">
                        <p class="item-text">
                            Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam
                            corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex 
                          </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item lunch">
                    <img src="/img/sandwhich.jpg">
                    <div class="item-info">
                        <header>
                        <h4>BLT Sandwhich</h4>
                        <h4 class="price">$20.99</h4>
                        </header>
                        <div class="stars">
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span> 
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="border">
                        <p class="item-text">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                            Repudiandae, sint quam. Et reprehenderit fugiat nesciunt inventore
                            laboriosam excepturi! Quo, officia.
                          </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item dinner">
                    <img src="/img/steak.jpg">
                    <div class="item-info">
                        <header>
                        <h4>Steak Filet</h4>
                        <h4 class="price">$38.99</h4>
                        </header>
                        <div class="stars">
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span> 
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="border">
                        <p class="item-text">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                            Repudiandae, sint quam. Et reprehenderit fugiat nesciunt inventore
                            laboriosam excepturi! Quo, officia.
                          </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item breakfast">
                    <img src="/img/waffle.jpg">
                    <div class="item-info">
                        <header>
                        <h4>Strawberry Waffle</h4>
                        <h4 class="price">$17.99</h4>
                        </header>
                        <div class="stars">
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span> 
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="border">
                        <p class="item-text">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                            Repudiandae, sint quam. Et reprehenderit fugiat nesciunt inventore
                            laboriosam excepturi! Quo, officia.
                          </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item lunch">
                    <img src="/img/wrap.jpg">
                    <div class="item-info">
                        <header>
                        <h4>Thai Chicken Wrap</h4>
                        <h4 class="price">$21.99</h4>
                        </header>
                        <div class="stars">
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span> 
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="border">
                        <p class="item-text">
                            Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur.
                          </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can use JavaScript to store the values of the h4 elements with class "price" in an array, and then sort the array:

```
//Select all h4 elements with class "price"
const priceElements = document.querySelectorAll("h4.price");
//Create an empty array to store the prices
let prices = [];
//Loop through the h4 elements and push the text content to the prices array
priceElements.forEach(price => {
    prices.push(parseFloat(price.textContent)); //parsing the float value
});
//Sort the prices array in ascending order
prices.sort((a, b) => a - b);

//For descending order
prices.sort((a, b) => b - a);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I will study this.

Comment: Now the problem is displaying this solution, Would I have to create another class for each food item to arrange them accordingly?

Comment: I am noticing when I add eventlistener to the button with this solution i am receiving NaN for each price